# Could anyone explain this theme

Tags: meaning

Theme: Innovative new age processes

This topic is for making a poster. I don't think I've found the right meaning for this topic.
(The topic is related to engineering)

Comment: Talk to one of your teachers.

Comment: Add some details on the project and what you think, ideas you've had. Very thin so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an engineer and *new age processes* are the sort of buzz words that you see on promotional material sometimes. A well-known buzzword that was popular about a decade ago was *internet-of-things*. That term is now rarely seen and it's interesting to reflect on why. Perhaps because in its success it became mundane? I mention it at least to suggest that *new age processes* is a similar term. If so, it's being used currently because technology is opening up some new possibility. Eventually, the buzzword will disappear because whatever it is will become rather mundane.

So, what have we here?

Googling "new age processes" backs up the buzzword theory. What new possibility has technology made available now?

> We are in the midst of the Fourth Industrial Revolution that’s blazing a digital trail across the manufacturing industry.
>
> *Source: [https://www.wipro.com/](https://www.wipro.com/process-and-industrial-manufacturing/10-transformation-areas-for-new-age-manufacturers/)*

Gripping...

> **1. Dawn of the Intelligent Factory**
>
> Intelligent Factories of today are transforming the plant value chain and connecting everything...

That's right, they're connecting everything...

> ...in a bid to enhance productivity, reduce workforce challenges, and drive operational efficiencies.

I'll spare you 2 through 4, although if you want to learn about how "operations transformation drives efficiencies" then treat yourself and click on the link.

Buzzwords aside, they have a point with something here:

> **5. Cloud first, Cloud only**
>
> Cloud gives manufacturers easy and low cost access to new tech, improves accessibility and collaboration while augmenting security, and provides opportunities to offer new services to their customers.

Today we routinely and casually use cloud storage on our phones, TVs, PCs, etc. Yesterday a friend visited - I used my phone to play (via the TV) a piece of music that I'd composed on my PC. So everything is, as advertised, connected.

It's so normal it's mundane. And true to form some people are thinking about it. And they're trying to find opportunities. And well, that's all just a lot easier to do when you have a buzzword - so today that's "new age processes."

Can we meet in the middle and just drop the "innovative", though?